# Removing a default Double or int

Tags: java

Hello I'm after a cleaner implementation of how to check for a defaulted doubled value such as -1.0

My implementation for strings is:

```
    private static String stringNullChecker(String o)
{
    if(o == null || o.equals("?") || o.equals(""))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return o;
    }
}
```

so I can just call it as follows:

```
obj.setExDestination(stringNullChecker(wrapperObj.getExchange()));
```

However if I try the same with doubles it will throw a null pointer error.

so the implementation is currently:

```
        if(doubleNullChecker(wrapperObj.getPrcCcy()) != null)
    {
        obj.setSettlCurrFxRate(wrapperObj.getPrcCcy());
    }
```

But I'm having to do this If statement for every double/int value. Which is a lot of repeated code, I'd like something to push this out into it's own atomic function but other than a Boolean I'm at a loss as what would be nice clean code.

Basically I only want to set the value if it has a non default value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in case of a null or default value. Do you want to return null in the case of the default value?

Comment: if they wrapperObj value is a default value of say -1 I do not want to set it on obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Primitive double**

`double` as a primitive type cannot hold null value. It only can hold -1.0, 0.0, or even NaN (a special float value, but I'm not very sure of it's behaviour).

So you cannot check if a **primitive** `double` variable is null.

Anyway you can do this:

```
public static double notNaN(double value, double defaultValue) {
   return Double.isNaN(value)? defaultValue: value;
}
```

**In case of a java.lang.Double**

If your properties are `Double` (it is... object representation of double) it *can* be null. Just in this case you can make a defaultValue checker method.

```
public static double notNull(Double doubleObj, double defaultValue) {
   return doubleObj == null? defaultValue: doubleObj.doubleValue();
}

// use this way (getPropertyDouble() returns a java.lang.Double)

notNull(myObj.getPropertyDouble(), -1.0);
```

**Your check**

If `if(o == null)` works it's because Java converts your o primitive double to java.lang.Double and makes an object comparison (check if this autoboxed double is null... but a boxed primitive value always is an existent object).

**Checking values for objects**

If you have a Double object and want to check it's value I should recommend:

```
doubleObj.equals(Double.valueOf(1.0D));
```

It is:

- use `equals` for comparison: you don't want to compare object references but values inside the object.
- compare against another Double object: that's why I wrote Double.valueOf(1.0D), to box the value explicitly.

**Setting the property**

Unluckily in Java there's no simple way of passing a method A by reference to another method B, in order to B executes A if some condition mets. You can use reflection but it's overkill I think. And there's no much sense to use some templating mechanism if what you want to do is reducing your code.

So... What I come up with is simply:

1. resetting the same value
2. setting a default known value

In the first case -"let the value as is"- you can do:

```
obj.setProperty(notNull(objWrapper.getProperty(), obj.getProperty()));
```

In this code you always set the value. If objWrapper has a null value (or whatever you check) the value to set to obj will be its own current value.

In the second case -"if not setted use a default"- you can do:

```
obj.setProperty(notNull(objWrapper.getProperty(), HERE_GOES_YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE));
```

Keep in mind that if your obj.setProperty is an object you can use null, otherwise you are forced to some constant value.

Comment: Your answer explains how to check for equality with the default value, but it does not solve his issue of only calling the setter method if the get method does not return the default value.

Comment: Right. I'll add a conclusion then.

Comment: > it only can hold -1.0, 0.0, or even NaN --

 Floats can hold 0.0 and -0.0, ±infinity and NaN in addition to all the other numbers